# Styling Google Translate Plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-translate, google-translation-api

I need some help styling and changing the way the Google Translate plugin works.

I'm implementing it on my website and the way I want it to work is just to have the initials of the language.

So by default is should en EN, and then when clicked a dropdown appears with FR, ES, DE.
First thing I'm having difficulty is just removing the google logo with a simple string "EN".

Is there any way to do what I want?
Here is a JSFiddle with my code - https://jsfiddle.net/7rLd4sg6/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Teste Google Dropdown</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Google Translate Test</p>

    <div id="google_translate_element">
      <span>EN</span>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
          new google.translate.TranslateElement(
            {
              pageLanguage: "pt",
              includedLanguages: "en,fr,es,de",
              layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
            },
            "google_translate_element"
          );
        }
      </script>
    </div>

    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?
cb=googleTranslateElementInit"
    >

      //Plugin Customize
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#google_translate_element').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
            $('.goog-te-menu-value span:first').html('LANGUAGE');
            $('.goog-te-menu-frame.skiptranslate').load(function(){
              setTimeout(function(){
                $('.goog-te-menu-frame.skiptranslate').contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item-selected .text').html('LANGUAGE');
              }, 100);
            });
          });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.